# Discord Button failed Pop up on command

Tags: javascript, button, menu, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a Menu for my Discord server and I've got the slash command working, but with I go to pull the menu I get: Main menu as a return in discord when executing the slash command.

I used the following code to get as far as I have:

```
    //Remember to run " node deploy-commands.js " to register your commands!

const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require('discord.js');


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('menu')
        .setDescription('Brings up the Main Menu'),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const row = new MessageActionRow()
                        .addComponents(
                                new MessageButton()
                                        .setCustomId('dice-bag')
                                        .setLabel('danger')
                                        .setStyle("DANGER"),
                                
                                new MessageButton()
                                        .setCustomId('spells')
                                        .setLabel('primary')
                                        .setStyle("PRIMARY"),
                                        
                                new MessageButton()
                                        .setCustomId('inventory')
                                        .setLabel('Success')
                                        .setStyle("SUCCESS"),
                        );
                        await interaction.reply({content: 'Main menu,', components: [row]})
    },
};
```

I have a feeling I need to embed the message somehow but am not 100% sure how. I'm pretty sure that I need to likely add something the:

```
await interaction.reply({content: 'Main menu,', components: [row]})
```

I'm pretty sure the ***components: [row]})*** is wrong but I'm not sure what to put in its place. anytime I try to fix it I get errors about MessageActionRow action row needing NEW.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The `compents` is wrong, it is obviously a misspelling of "components." Can you edit your question to include the code for what you tried that was getting you the error about the `MessageActionRow` "needing NEW"? That is most likely closer to the proper answer than the current code in your question.

Comment: It was just a case of my stupid fingers typing too fast once I did that call change it works like a charm. 

Thank you @Cannicide

Answer (score 0):

*Note! This is assuming you are using Discord.js v13.2.0.*

---

According to the documentation, [`<MessageActionRow>.addComponents(...)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.2.0/class/MessageActionRow?scrollTo=addComponents) expects an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of [MessageActionRowComponentResolveables](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.2.0/typedef/MessageActionRowComponentResolvable). This look something like this:

```js
<MessageActionRow>.addComponents([
new MessageButton().setValue("option1").setStyle("PRIMARY"),
new MessageButton().setValue("option2").setStyle("DANGER")
]);
```

The important thing to note here is the usage of braces (`[]`). In JavaScript, braces indicate an Array. In your code, you are missing the braces.

```js
// DON'T do this!
<MessageActionRow>.addComponents(new MessageButton, new MessageButton);

// DO this!
<MessageActionRow>.addComponents([ new MessageButton, new MessageButton ]);
```

With that, your code isn't too different. All you have to do is add the braces.

```js
<MessageActionRow>.addComponents([
new MessageButton()
.setCustomId('dice-bag')
.setLabel('danger')
.setStyle("DANGER"),

new MessageButton()
.setCustomId('spells')
.setLabel('primary')
.setStyle("PRIMARY"),
                                        
new MessageButton()
.setCustomId('inventory')
.setLabel('Success')
.setStyle("SUCCESS")
]);
```

Comment: Is there a reason I need the braces? It is posting the buttons without them I'm only asking for the sake of learning.

Comment: The braces indicate an array and sometimes, functions may require them.